# Ubuntu on Zbook G5 using TB HP G2 dock - internet works but not 4k external USB-C connected screen

Tags: hp, monitor, dock

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Hardware model: HP HP ZBook Studio G5

I have had a HP G2 120W dock working with my external 4k screen, however the USB-C cable on that dock is a bit damaged so I have got another G2 dock. Now I am not able to get the USB-C screen working with the new dock.

I have tried https://liejuntao001.medium.com/hp-thunderbolt-g2-dock-works-with-ubuntu-19-10-a59814b5a86d without success.

dmesg give no entries when connecting the monitor USB-C cable into the dock.

When connecting the USB-C connector from the screen into the old dock it doesn't take long (this time. It could take quite a few minutes sometimes) before the 4k screen is found and lit up.

What could possibly be needed to get the new dock working?

The internet works on both docks and the new dock is Authorized in Settings > Privacy > Thunderbolt.

Comment: Anyone? ………………..